# How to return a double from a lambda with int parameter

Tags: python, lambda

I wrote this lambda for a sigmoid function:

```
sigmoid = lambda x: 1 / (1 + np.exp(-x))
```

I use this on arrays to calculate the sigmoid obviously.

Python gives me a warning:

```
RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in exp
```

for this statement. How do I fix it?

The values that are sent to this lambda are floating point numbers.

Comment: Sounds like you should just be using [`scipy.special.expit`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.special.expit.html).

Comment: I am working on an assignment which only allows me to work with numpy. The outputs are coming alright, just that I do not know how this warning may affect me.

Comment: your values of `x` are most likely too large for the exponential - remember the `exp(-x)` of a large negative number is truly large i.e. `exp(|x|)` so you will encounter your problem.

Comment: The warning means `np.exp(-x)` returned infinity, because floating-point numbers don't go high enough to represent the result. That's fine for this computation, but you could [turn off overflow warnings](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.seterr.html) or avoid the overflow if you want. (`scipy.special.expit` wouldn't produce this warning.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Deal with overflow in exp using numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9559346/deal-with-overflow-in-exp-using-numpy)

Comment: The only issue with a silently treating these `errors` could be an issue in your model (I am assuming that you are using some sort of regression or ML problem) where not seeing large negative values (where there should not be any) would lead to your results being off..

Comment: you should check the value of x in your code before it passes through the sigma function..

Answer (score 1):

[numpy.clip](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.clip.html)

np.clip could also work on a `x` array all at once

```
import sys   
import numpy as np

xmax = np.log(sys.float_info.max)

sigmoid = lambda x: 1 / (1 + np.exp(np.clip(-x, a_min=None, a_max=xmax)))

sigmoid(-10000)
Out[155]: 5.5626846462681369e-309
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`numpy.seterr`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.seterr.html)

`numpy.seterr()` **always** returns a dictionary with the current handling of different numerical errors, that by default are

```
>>> seterr()
{'divide': 'warn', 'over': 'warn', 'under': 'ignore', 'invalid': 'warn'}
>>>
```

To change one of these behaviours **and saving the current defaults** you can
do

```
>>> def_handlers = np.seterr(over='ignore')
```

then you can do your sigmoid evaluation and at the end you could restore the defaults

```
>>> np.seterr(**def_handlers);
```

Consider that the array of sigmoid values may now contain `inf` entries, your code **has** to deal with this eventuality.