# Implement softmax function with numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, machine-learning

My current function is as follows:

```
def soft_max(z):
    t = np.exp(z)
    a = np.exp(z) / np.sum(t, axis=1)
    return a
```

However I get the error: `ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (20,10) (20,)` since np.sum(t, axis=1) isn't a scalar.

I want to have `t / the sum of each row` but I don't know how to do this.

Comment: Use `keepdims` : `np.sum(t, axis=1, keepdims=True)`?

Comment: I tried that and i get a lot of `RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in exp`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40726490/overflow-error-in-pythons-numpy-exp-function, https://nolanbconaway.github.io/blog/2017/softmax-numpy, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9559346/deal-with-overflow-in-exp-using-numpy?

Answer (score 4):

You want to do something like (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42606665/7207392) post)

```
def softmax(x, axis=None):
    x = x - x.max(axis=axis, keepdims=True)
    y = np.exp(x)
    return y / y.sum(axis=axis, keepdims=True)
```

Answer (score 3):

As of version 1.2.0, scipy includes softmax as a special function:

https://scipy.github.io/devdocs/generated/scipy.special.softmax.html

Use the `axis` argument do run it over rows.

```
from scipy.special import softmax
softmax(arr, axis=0)
```

Answer (score 2):

suppose your `z` is a 2 dimensional array, try

```
def soft_max(z):
    t = np.exp(z)
    a = np.exp(z) / np.sum(t, axis=1).reshape(-1,1)
    return a
```

Comment: sorry,  `np.sum(t, axis=1, keepdims=True)` is better than using `.reshape`. they both are doing the same thing. `Overflow` may be caused by your input data I think.