# Not able to plot with large parameters value

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I want to plot the beta distribution with `beta.pdf(x, a, b)` but I only get the following error:

> **FloatingPointError: underflow encountered in exp**.

This is my code:

```
x = np.linspace(0, 1, 990)
a=50.5
b=940.5

y = beta.pdf(x, a, b)

plt.title("PDF of Beta (Bell-shape)", fontsize=20)
plt.xlabel("X", fontsize=16)
plt.ylabel("Probability Density", fontsize=16)
plt.plot(x, y, linewidth=3, color='firebrick')
plt.annotate("Beta(50.5,940.5)", xy=(0.15, 2), size = 100, ha='center', va='center', color='firebrick')

fig = plt.gcf()
plt.show()


fig.savefig('my_plot.png',dpi=130)
```

Comment: Works for me. Can you include the versions of the different modules?

Comment: how to know the version of the modules. Can u please help me as it works for u but not for me.

Comment: I am assuming you are using scipy.stats? If so you can find scipy version using `print(scipy.__version__)`

Comment: yup, it is showing 1.4.1 version for scipy

Comment: OK, its probably your numpy then. What version is that? `print(np.__version__)`

Comment: numpy version is 1.18.1

Comment: matplotlib version is 3.1.3

Comment: I updated some packages. Now it is working perfectly for me as well. Thank you @DavidG

Comment: Which packages did you update exactly? I'm facing the same problem right now.

Comment: I was using anaconda that was not the updated version. So, first, I update my anaconda with `conda update conda` then I update all the packages with `conda update --all`. then above implementation works for me. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same problem while trying to create a [seaborn violin plot](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.violinplot.html). Thus, I updated the packages *scipy, matplotlib, numpy* and *seaborn* with the following commands:

```
pip install --upgrade scipy
pip install --upgrade matplotlib
pip install --upgrade numpy
pip install --upgrade seaborn
```

Unfortunately, that didn't help either, so I ended up using the *seterr* method of numpy to simply ignore this warning (as described in [this old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24769951/9805238)). You can set it as follows at the beginning of your code:

```
numpy.seterr(under='ignore')
```